# how to use mocha for testing a file I've already written

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js, chai

Most mocha tutorials I find start with a blank file and they start writing new functions inside of a test file that are very simple. I don't understand how to implement mocha with an application I've already written. I've already written a .js file that uses post, put, get, and delete. As far as I can tell, they all work the way they're supposed to, but I want to add mocha/chai into my program. I don't understand how I'm supposed to do this.

Take the POST function for example. Am I supposed to write the function inside of the /test folder and use the mocha there? Do I need to have the function written in both my test file and in my main, index.js file? If I test the function with mocha in /test, does it implement the exact same way as it would if it were in index.js - that is, will the function actually post to my database or will it just test the function's ability to do so?

Comment: When you write a test file you should import the function you're trying to test. I don't really understand the question but I think thats what you're hinting at.

Answer (score 0):

tests don't change the behavior of anything...or at least they shouldn't. We write tests to ensure that the code does what we think it does. If you had a javascript file that makes requests you would then write tests that stub or "fake" the window in a separate test file and then expect the details of those calls to match what you expected them to. typically you'll set up your webpacker to look for all test files and then run an npm command to run all of your tests and make sure they pass. Keep your test files as separate file from your javascript files but it's usually helpful to keep everything organized. This entire reply is only surrounded around the idea that you are unintentionally asking about unit tests.